# What is the purpose of this line of code if (hours == 00) { hours = 12; } please explain to me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know in this code what is the meaning of the line of code asked in the question why this code is used. Can you tell me what the meaning of this line is? I wonder what the use of this line is.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      function showTime() {
        // To Get the current time/date
        var date = new Date();
        //Make Variables to get hours, minute, and second
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var min = date.getMinutes();
        var sec = date.getSeconds();
        // AM, PM Setting
        var session = "AM";   
        // Conditions for time behavior
    
        if (hours == 00) {
          hours = 12;
        }
    
        if (hours >= 12) {
          session = "PM";
        }
    
        if (hours > 12) {
          hours = hours - 12;
        }
    
        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        min = min < 10 ? "0" + min : min;
        sec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;
    
        // Set the variable to span
    
        $("#hours").text(hours);
        $("#min").text(min);
        $("#sec").text(sec);
        $("#period").text(session);
    
        // To change time in every seconds
        setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
      }
      showTime();
    });
```

Comment: When you are using Time in 24 Hours Format then 00 is equal to 12

Comment: If the hours is 0 make it 12?

Comment: There is no hour 0 on a 12-hour clock.

Comment: `00` should be `0`. Leading zeros are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If the hour is 00, meaning 12 in the morning (midnight), it changes the string value to show '12' instead of '00', in order to display the time in 12-hour format.